# MvcSiteMapProvider and Autofac issue with InstancePerRequest

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac, mvcsitemapprovider

I've installed nutget package `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.Autofac.Modules`. 
I'm trying to register my DBContext as InstancePerRequest. This however fails with the error

```
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
```

If I change my DBContext to InstancePerLifetimeScope, all is well. The error is thrown in the file

```
DI\Autofac\Modules\MvcSiteMapProviderModule.cs    Line: 195
```

Actually, if I try to register any of my own types with InstancePerRequest, I get this error. I'm new to Autofac so don't really understand a lot of the code in the nuget package for`MvcSiteMapProvider` Autofac. While I'm learning more about Autofac, hoping someone can point in the right direction as to how to get around this issue?

EDIT:

From Autofac docs, I'm getting the error because:

```
Code is running during application startup (e.g., in an ASP.NET Global.asax) that uses dependency resolution when there isn’t an active request yet.
```

According to MvcSiteMapProvider docs, this line is required though, so can I move this somewhere else?

```
// Setup global sitemap loader (required)
MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = container.Resolve<ISiteMapLoader>();
```

EDIT 2:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // BEGIN: Autofac Config
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

    // Register context and unit of work here
    IoC.Dependencies.Register.RegisterTypes(builder);

    builder.RegisterModule(new MvcSiteMapProviderModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new MvcModule());

    var container = builder.Build();

    MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = container.Resolve<ISiteMapLoader>();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    // END: Autofac Config

    Helpers.Log4NetManager.InitializeLog4Net();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

Comment: Please post your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) including how it is called from startup. It sounds like you are attempting to register types outside of the composition root, which is not valid. The entire container should be constructed before the Loader is instantiated. Also, it is not valid to access `HttpContext` or `RequestContext` inside of a service constructor because at that point in time the request is not yet active.

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, I take it that's my Application_Start in Global.asax? See update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering your controllers twice with Autofac.

```
// This registers the all of the controllers in the application
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

// And so does this...
builder.RegisterModule(new MvcModule());
```

Contents of `MvcModule`:

```
public class MvcModule
    : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var currentAssembly = typeof(MvcModule).Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(currentAssembly)
            .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

From [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/558):

> The error pretty much says it all - something in your registrations has a dependency that is registered as InstancePerRequest and it's being resolved outside of a web request.

---

I am not sure that registering `DBContext` as `InstancePerRequest` is such a good idea. `MvcSiteMapProvider` loads before any request context is created, so if you are using dynamic node providers or custom `ISiteMapNodeProvider` implementations that access the database, it isn't going to work. A better choice would be to use `InstancePerDependency` which is not dependent upon `HttpContext`.

### [Instance Per Dependency](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#id1)

Also called ‘transient’ or ‘factory’ in other containers. Using per-dependency scope, a unique instance will be returned from each request for a service.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the RegisterControllers line. I've changed registering my context back as InstancePerRequest, but I still get the original 'No scope with a matching tag.......' error.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I'll leave the InstacePerRequest alone. Thanks for your help.